Al llamar a "SKBitmap.Encode(format, quality)" estableciendo un argumento para "quality" distinto a 100, la imagen se muestra en escala de grises
Al llamar al método SKBitmap.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat format, int quality) con el parámetro format establecido en SKEncodedImageFormat.Webp y un argumento para el parámetro quality distinto de 100 convierte mi imagen a escala de grises.
Estoy desarrollando una app con NET MAUI y estoy usando el paquete SkiaSharp 2.88.8 para realizar la conversión de una imagen a formato WebP, pero al probar la app en un dispositivo Android durante el proceso de conversión la imagen es modificada a escala de grises, lo cual no deseo que ocurra, quiero que mantenga su color original.
He depurado la aplicación y me he dado cuenta que esto ocurre al llamar al método SKBitmap.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat format, int quality) con el parámetro format establecido en SKEncodedImageFormat.Webp y un argumento para el parámetro quality distinto de 100.
La cuestión es que, aunque conozco el punto exacto del problema, desconozco a que se debe y como solucionarlo.
Aquí esta el código de mi método de conversión:
    async Task NotifyCompletedLoadFile(Task<byte[]> task)
    {
        ConversionState = "¡Decodificando imagen!";
        using var bmp = SKBitmap.Decode(task.Result);

        ConversionState = "¡Convirtiendo imagen!";
        // Si establezco "quality" a 100 todo bien, pero cualquier otro número
        // (por ejemplo 50) convierte la imagen ha escala de grises.
        var webpData = bmp.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Webp, 50);

        ConversionState = "¡Guardando imagen!";
        using var output = File.OpenWrite(NewFilePath);
        webpData.SaveTo(output);

        ConversionState = "¡Operación terminada!";
    }


Y no sera un problema de la libreria?

otra cosa.. tu metodo es async, devuelve un task, pero no veo en ningun lado un await...

es para poder ejecutarlo en segundo plano, y no en el thread de la UI

si.. se de eso.. pero si no hay nada awaitable, entonces no hay otro thread que se levante, y no hay nada que hacer para la ui porque no hay esperas... entiendo que pasas un task ya ejecutado, o sea solo te interesa el resultado, lo raro es que si mandaste a ejecutar una tarea, como sabes si esta acabo o no???... algo en tu codigo no me cuadra, pero igual, el problema que describis parece de la libreria y no de algo que podamos solucionar aca...

Entiendo la confusión y agradezco la observación, he refactorizado tantas veces el método para implementar distintas soluciones , que se me han escapado por ahí algunas cosillas. En una implementación requería ejecutar la tarea mediante "Task.Run" obviamente sin el parámetro actual, y en la implementación actual estaba usando el encadenamiento de tareas a través de "Task.ContinueWith", de ahí el parámetro, el cual representa la tarea anterior ya concluida.

En cuanto a tu respuesta, realmente estoy esperanzado en que no sea un problema de la librería, porque es esta implementación, la solución con mayor rendimiento en cuanto a la conversión de imagenes a webp, especificamente para este proyecto, y me dolería tener que usar otra como ImageSharp, que si funciona pero tarda aprox 3min, en cuanto a Web APIs la mayoría son de pago por uso, y sus planes free, no satisfacen mi carga de trabajo.

Una función Task puede ser ejecutada con o sin retorno (void), y con o sin await, no hay problema en eso

Será lo mismo que este bug https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/2643 ??

Muchas gracias @Yussef, al parecer es el mismo problema que presento.

Afortunadamente he encontrado la solución ha mi problema.
Es un problema interno relacionado a las dependencias del paquete SkiaSharp 2.88.8. La solución es actualizar dicho paquete a la versión preliminar SkiaSharp 3.0.0-preview.3.1.
Agradecimiento especial a Yussef por compartir el vinculo sobre un problema relacionado
